# Finding fields with non alfa numeric values

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am looking a way to find the values in a column that has non alfa numeric values...

I tried
select 'kjh$'  not RLIKE '([0-9][a-z]|[A-Z])*')
but does not work

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `REGEXP '^[A-Za-z0-9]+$'` or `RLIKE '^[A-Za-z0-9]+$'`.
Sample SQL -

```
select  * from my table where mycol not RLIKE '^[A-Za-z0-9]+$'
```

`^` - determines start of the string
`$` - end of the string
`+` - match the preceding character one or more times
`[A-Za-z0-9]` - to check alphanumeric or not

I ran a simple select statement to check if a string has alphanumeric or not using regex and here is the output.
`select  'Aa90$$bc' ,'Aa90$$bc' rlike '^[A-Za-z0-9]+$'`

[image: sample output]